# Connect the IIS Web Server MSSQL from Linux shared hosting

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel

I have deployed the **Laravel web application** on the Linux A2 shared hosting server. There is I want to use **sqlsrv** driver to connect the MSSQL database.
The MSSQL database is on the IIS web server. I had enabled `pdo_sqlsrv, pdo_odbc, odbc, and sqlsrv` extension in my server, opened the **1433** port to communicate, and my Linux server is whitelisted at the IIS web server too. But, when I try to connect it gives me the below error.

`Code: -49`
`Error: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712.`

I was gone through many solutions but no success.

Comment: Have you downloaded said driver and installed it?

Comment: For that, I had contacted the server guy but they said that, since you are hosted on a shared server, we may not able to install any custom drivers. So, any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: You can't use an extension that requires drivers without installing said drivers.